# Android setting View with PopupWindow to invisible without invoking PopupWindow 's onDismiss

Tags: android, popupwindow

In my app I'm trying to set a view containint a `popupwindow` to invisible and after some time to visible. My popup contains images and text and I want the whole view with the popup and it's content to be shown and not shown based on some logic.
My problem is that setting it to invisible causing the `popupwindow`'s`dismiss()` to be called.

Any way to change that?

Comment: can't you just show/dismiss it instead of change its visibility?

Comment: that way I will have to build my popup again with its images and such, every time I want to show it again.

Comment: is it that expensive ? Can't you just keep a *global reference*  to the popup?

Comment: I've edited the question. As you can see, your suggestion is possible but is a little painfull in my situation as I have to take care of the view containing the popup as well. My goal is simply to set the whole view to visible and invisible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could set the view's alpha to 0 for invisible and 1 for visible.

Comment: This is really more of a comment than an answer.